# how to use if condition in jquery table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, if-statement, freshworks

```
 <tr>
            <td id="id">${interaction_search[i].id}</td>
            <td id="date">${interaction_search[i].created_at}</td>
            <td id="status">${interaction_search[i].status}</td>
            <td id="sub">${interaction_search[i].subject}</td>
            <td id="resolution">${interaction_search[i].due_by}</td>
</tr>;
```

above code is for table display

```
                if ((interaction_search[i].status === "2")) {
                    interaction_search[i].status = "open";
                } else if ((interaction_search[i].status === "3")) {
                    interaction_search[i].status = "pending";
                } else if ((interaction_search[i].status === "4")) {
                    interaction_search[i].status = "resolved";
                } else if ((interaction_search[i].status === "5")) {
                    interaction_search[i].status = "closed";
                }
```

i need to write this condition for the `interaction_search[i].status` in the table

Answer (score 0):

Make a function and return the string.

```js
const statusText = {
  2: 'open',
  3: 'pending',
  4: 'resolved',
  5: 'closed',
}
function getStatusText (status) {
  return statusText[status] || 'unknown';
}
```

and call the function in your string template literal

```js
const foo = `
    <td id="status">${getStatusText(interaction_search[i].status)}</td>
`;
```